# Cannot open folder in a docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am really new in working with Docker. Now I want to open a particular folder in the Docker container so that I could save created Jupyter Notebook files. I am doing it on Windows 10.
If I try to do it this way:

```
 docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v C:/Users/Larry/AI/bootcamp:/home/jovyan/bootcamp --rm --name jupyter jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
```

I get an error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /home/jovyan/bootcamp.
```

If I do it this way:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /User/Larry/AI/bootcamp:/home/jovyan/bootcamp --rm --name jupyter jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
```

The container is created and I can create a new Jupyter file, but it is not saved. Does anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604) - the `:` in `C:` is confusing the argument parser.

The workaround might be simply to rewrite the volume mount as mentioned in the github issue:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/path/with:colon,destination=/mnt
```

### Update

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 --mount type=bind,source=C:/Users/Larry/AI/bootcamp,destination=/home/jovyan/bootcamp --rm --name jupyter jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
```

Comment: Just don't understand what it is missing: $ docker run --mount type=bind,source=C:/Users/Larry/AI,destination=/mnt
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.

Comment: You need to plug the "--mount ... " part into your invokation, instead of the "-v ..." part that you currently have there